# Nodejs, Mongoose, Express: type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Account' not working

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

I am just getting started in the MEAN stack and can't seem to get my object ID shared across multiple schemas.

In a nutshell: I want the object Id from Account model to be stored as the Object Id in my Profile Model.

I am using localpassport authentication. The following is my App.js file, routes, and models.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**App.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
var Profile = require('./models/profile');
var Account = require('./models/account');
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Account.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(Account.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Account.deserializeUser());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myapp');


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

**Index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var Account = require('../models/account');
var Profile = require('../models/profile');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { user : req.user });
});

router.get('/register', function(req, res) {
    res.render('register', { });
});

router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    Account.register(new Account({ username : req.body.username }), req.body.password, function(err, account) {
    if (err) {
        return res.render('register', { account : account });
    }

    passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
        res.redirect('/');
    });        
   });
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', { user : req.user });
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/profile');
});

router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});

router.get('/profile', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('profile', { user : req.user});
});

router.post('/profile', function(req, res) {
    var basicProfile = new Profile();

    basicProfile.firstname = req.body.firstname,
    basicProfile.middlename = req.body.middlename,
    basicProfile.lastname = req.body.lastname,
    basicProfile.contactinfo.phonenumber = req.body.phonenumber,
    basicProfile.contactinfo.address.street = req.body.street,
    basicProfile.contactinfo.address.city = req.body.city,
    basicProfile.contactinfo.address.state = req.body.state,
    basicProfile.contactinfo.address.zip = req.body.zip

    basicProfile.save(function(err, profile){
        if(err){
        return res.render('profile', { profile : profile });
        }
        return res.redirect('/');
    });
});

router.get('/ping', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).send("pong!");
});

router.get('/profile', function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile')
})

module.exports = router;
```

**Account Model**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var Account = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});

Account.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', Account);
```

**Profile Model**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProfileSchema = new Schema({
    _creator: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account'}],

    firstname: String,
    middlename: String,
    lastname: String,
    contactinfo: {
        phonenumber: String,
        address: {
            street: String,
            city: String,
            state: String,
            zip: String
        }
    }

});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Profile', ProfileSchema);
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question of problem? You posted all your code but it's not clear at all what you already tried to associate both models, and why it failed.

Comment: When the code runs it adds to my db.profile collection, but the "_creator" show as an empty array. So, it never registers the ObjectId from the Account model and I am not sure why. According to the mongoose docs it should be a simply reference such as I have in the code but it simply returns an empty Array. I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Where are you associating an account to a profile in your code? It's difficult to follow the code with all the added noise :-(

Comment: I just found it. Thank you for that! I just added code. My "_creator" field was a blank array because I was never assigning that value to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Profile.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProfileSchema = new Schema({
    _creator: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account'}],

    firstname: String,
    middlename: String,
    lastname: String,
    contactinfo: {
        phonenumber: String,
        address: {
            street: String,
            city: String,
            state: String,
            zip: String
        }
    }

});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Profile', ProfileSchema);
```

**Index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var Account = require('../models/account');
var Profile = require('../models/profile');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { user : req.user });
});

router.get('/register', function(req, res) {
    res.render('register', { });
});

router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    Account.register(new Account({ username : req.body.username }), req.body.password, function(err, account) {
    if (err) {
        return res.render('register', { account : account });
    }

    passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
        res.redirect('/');
    });        
   });
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', { user : req.user });
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/profile');
});

router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});

router.get('/profile', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('profile', { user : req.user});
});

router.post('/profile', function(req, res) {
    var basicProfile = new Profile();

    basicProfile._creator = req.user._id
    basicProfile.firstname = req.body.firstname,
    basicProfile.middlename = req.body.middlename,
    basicProfile.lastname = req.body.lastname,
    basicProfile.contactinfo.phonenumber = req.body.phonenumber,
    basicProfile.contactinfo.address.street = req.body.street,
    basicProfile.contactinfo.address.city = req.body.city,
    basicProfile.contactinfo.address.state = req.body.state,
    basicProfile.contactinfo.address.zip = req.body.zip

    basicProfile.save(function(err, profile){
        if(err){
        return res.render('profile', { profile : profile });
        }
        return res.redirect('/');
    });
});

router.get('/ping', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).send("pong!");
});

router.get('/profile', function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile')
})

module.exports = router;
```

Added _creator to the route targeting the user's id from the database which now associates that object id to the user profile schema.

If anyone reading this sees a problem with this answer please comment and let me know. I.E. security concerns down the road, scalability, querying, etc.

Thanks and thanks to [robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep) for getting me down that path.