# Why does the secondaryUser field affect wether findOne works?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

In this I am using nodejs with express and mongoose. My question is how does changing the secondaryUser field affect whether or not the findOne works? If I have it as friends.id it works and it finds the right profile, but I want to tie it to the user field in the profile. If I change it to friends.user.id the findOne fails and it sends the 404 error in the catch.

```
router.post(
  "/:handle",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", {
    session: false
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    Profile.findOne({ handle: req.params.handle }).then(friends => {
      const newFriend = new Friend({
        initialAccepted: true,
        initialUser: req.user.id,
        secondaryUser: friends.id
      });

      newFriend
        .save()
        .then(Friend => res.json(Friend))
        .catch(err =>
          res.status(404).json({
            friendnotfound: "No people found with that handle"
          })
        );
    });
  }
);
```

The schema used for friend is

```
const FriendSchema = new Schema({
  initialUser: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "profile"
  },

  secondaryUser: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "profile"
  },

  initialAccepted: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },

  initialSecondary: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },

  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  }
});
```

This is the schema for the profile

```
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users"
  },
  handle: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 40
  },
  bio: {
    type: String
  },
  platforms: {
    type: [String]
  },
  website: {
    type: String
  },

  social: {
    youtube: {
      type: String
    },
    twitter: {
      type: String
    },
    facebook: {
      type: String
    },
    linkedin: {
      type: String
    },
    twitch: {
      type: String
    }
  },

  games: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String
      },
      platform: {
        type: String
      },
      handle: {
        type: String
      },
      rank: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ],

  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

Comment: Passport is setting req.user but there might not be friends.user . Please share model schema and data passed in req.parmas.handle for more details

Comment: ok will make an edit with the schema

Comment: Hi, maybe this answer can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36956943/nodejs-mongoose-express-type-schema-objectid-ref-account-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Follow proper naming convention for variables

```
Profile.findOne({ handle: req.params.handle }).then(profile => { // changed name from friends to profile
    const newFriend = new Friend({
        initialAccepted: true,
        initialUser: req.user.id,
        secondaryUser: profile.id // changed name from friends to profile
        // profile.user.id (ref to user table not provided in schema)
    });
```

if you give profile.user.id the object will not get created ( checking for id inside profile schema but user id provided)

Friend Schema:

```
 secondaryUser: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "profile" // checking for id inside profile schema
      },
```